# Cannot save video using cv2.VideoWriter after transforming image

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to save videos from a movement detection system I built using OpenCv2 with Python on Ubuntu.

However, I'm only able to save the frames to a video file if I write the raw frames. If I try to transform it in any way, such as **imutils.resize**, or **cv2.cvtColor** it wont save.

Below is a snippet of the code that I'm using.

```
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
outSecurity = cv2.VideoWriter(fileName+"security.avi",fourcc,20.0,(1600,1200))

while True:
    frame = vs.read()
    frame = frame[1]
    outSecurity.write(frame) #this frame is written to file

    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=500)
    outSecurity.write(frame) #this frame IS NOT written to file

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (21, 21), 0)
    outSecurity.write(gray) #this frame IS NOT written to file
```

**EDIT:**

There were two errors in my code.

1. As highlighted by @Micka's comment, the gray scale image is 1-channel only and the **VideoWriter** was prepared to receive 3-channel images.
   I found out two ways to solve that. By configuring **VideoWriter** to work without colors or by changing the dimension of the image.
2. The second error was regarding **VideoWrite's** resolution. In the function **imutils.resize** I resized the image to (500,375), however, my **VideoWriter** was set to (1600,1200).

With all being said, below, the revised and working code.

```py
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
#VideoWriter accepting 1-channel images and fixing resolution
outGray = cv2.VideoWriter(fileName+"gray.avi",fourcc,20.0,(500,375),0)
#VideoWriter accepting 3-channel images and fixing resolution
outGeneral = cv2.VideoWriter(fileName+"general.avi",fourcc,20.0,(500,375))

while True:
    frame = vs.read()
    frame = frame[1]

    #Output image since resolution was fixed
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=500)
    outGeneral.write(frame) #this frame is written to file

    #Output image using VideoWriter only for 1-channel images
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (21, 21), 0)
    outGray.write(gray) #this frame is written to file

    #Change image to 3-channel version
    grey_temp = cv2.merge((gray,gray,gray))
    outGeneral.write(grey_temp) #this frame is written to file
```

Comment: your VideoWriter is parametrized to use 3-channel images, but you converted to single-channel by rgb2gray conversion. Convert back to 3 channel before writing

Comment: Thank you @Micka, you are correct. Based on your response, I was able to understand and fix my code. I added everything I did to my question

Comment: OpenCV is definitely not debug-friendly, it silently hides many errors and manages files in an obscure way (doesn't differentiate true I/O errors with end of file for instance, both return success = False). I had the same problem of a single channel frame not written into a file (well a few kB were written, but the video was not readable), your post provided me the solution to recreate a writable 3-channel frame (`isColor=False` doesn't work, even in Windows).